# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type Dars does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ienumerator

I have a list Dars

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PantaRei.Components
{
    public class Dars
    {
        public float OpBal      { get; set; }
        public float PlNeOrRec  { get; set; }
        public float MiCaCol    { get; set; }
        public float MiDeCol    { get; set; }
        public float MiWrOff    { get; set; }
        public float ClBal      { get; set; }

        public float Tot
        {
            get { return OpBal+ PlNeOrRec+ MiCaCol + MiDeCol + MiWrOff; }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a new dars

```
Dars secA1 = new Dars();
```

And Then I use this bit of code to fill it up

```
public static void GetData(ref Dars secA1, Ddr ddr, Ddrs ddrs, Type pTypes)
    {
        Array typesEnum = Enum.GetValues(pTypes);

        foreach (Enum types in typesEnum)
        {
            string pType = StringEnum.GetStringValue(types);

            secA1.OpBal = ddrs.Out.Sum(o => o.Amount);

            secA1.MiDeCol += ddr.Dil.Where(dil => dil.ProductType == pType && dil.ToBeSold).Sum(dil => dil.Amount);

            secA1.PlNeOrRec += ddr.Rec.Where(rec => rec.ToBeSold).Sum(rec => rec.Amount);

            GetMiCaCol(ref secA1, ddr, pType);
            GetMiWrOff(ref secA1, ddr, pType);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to do something like this

```
int i = 11;
            foreach (float g in secA1)
            {
                daily.Cells[i, 4] = g;
                i++;
            }
```

But I'm getting this error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'PantaRei.Components.Dars' because 'PantaRei.Components.Dars' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

How do I solve this?

Comment: Frankly I'd solve that by not trying to foreach over something that clearly isn't a collection

Comment: Ok, how do I turn it into a collection?

Comment: but... But... It *isn't* a collection... Pretending iy is would be very atypical

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just because a class has a collection of properties that happen to be `float`s, it doesn't make it a collection.  Your code appears to be doing what would be done a lot more appropriately with some sort of data binding.  What you are attempting to do *can* be done by marking `Dars` as implementing the `IEnumerable` interface, and adding an implementation of the `GetEnumerator` method that returns the values for the float properties in your class, but I would never condone this approach in a code review.  That being said, try this (if you must):

```
public class Dars : IEnumerable
{
    public float OpBal { get; set; }
    public float PlNeOrRec { get; set; }
    public float MiCaCol { get; set; }
    public float MiDeCol { get; set; }
    public float MiWrOff { get; set; }
    public float ClBal { get; set; }

    public float Tot
    {
        get { return OpBal + PlNeOrRec + MiCaCol + MiDeCol + MiWrOff; }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.OpBal;
        yield return this.PlNeOrRec;
        yield return this.MiCaCol;
        yield return this.MiDeCol;
        yield return this.MiWrOff;
        yield return this.ClBal;
        yield return this.Tot;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks. It works. Yes, I also don't like this aproach, but this is exactly what I need. I will only have one Dars, not a list of it and I do need to iterate trought it.

Comment: I do have to admit I'm not much of a developer. So I ask you, how would you do?

Answer (score 6):

It's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to do, but you *might* want to just implement a method returning an `IEnumerable<float>` using an iterator block:

```
public class Dars
{
    public float OpBal      { get; set; }
    public float PlNeOrRec  { get; set; }
    public float MiCaCol    { get; set; }
    public float MiDeCol    { get; set; }
    public float MiWrOff    { get; set; }
    public float ClBal      { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<float> GetValues()
    {
        yield return OpBal;
        yield return PlNeOrRec;
        yield return MiCaCol;
        yield return MiDeCol;
        yield return MiWrOff;
        yield return ClBal;
    }

    public float Tot
    {
        get { return OpBal+ PlNeOrRec+ MiCaCol + MiDeCol + MiWrOff; }
    }
}
```

... or you could create a `List<float>` or a `float[]` and return that from the method instead:

```
public IEnumerable<float> GetValues()
{
    return new[] { OpBal, PlNeOrRec, MiCaCol, MiDeCol, MiWrOff, ClBal };
}
```

Of course, you should adjust the order if that's not what you want.

(As an aside, those are pretty ghastly property names. Are they really what your code exposes?)